# CircleCI - speeding up jobs that share a Docker Image

Tags: circleci, circleci-2.0

I moved from a single `CircleCI` job with many steps to 3 different jobs with individual steps.

[image]

I like the new set up as Job 2 ( `run_script_inside_con` ) and Job 3 ( `scan_container_with_` ) don't start until job 1 completes and they start in parallel.

In job 1 (`build_container`) it primarily downloads a source image from Docker Hub.  This takes time as the Base Image which is nearly 500MB.  This job issues `docker build` and `docker save`.

Job 2 and 3 start by `setup_remote_docker`, `attach_workspace` and `docker load` so they can load to the compressed file.

`Docker load` takes nearly 1 minute in Job 2 and 3.  **As a newbie to CircleCI, is there an obvious efficiency improvement here to save time here?**

I have used `docker_layer_caching: true` where I thought appropriate.

```
version: 2.1

executors:
  my-executor:
    docker:
      - image: cimg/python:3.9.7

jobs:
  build_container:
    executor: my-executor

    steps:
      - setup_remote_docker:
          docker_layer_caching: true

      - checkout

      - run:
          name: Echo system information
          command: |-
            echo "Hello ${CIRCLE_USERNAME}"
            echo "A container tag: ${CIRCLE_PROJECT_REPONAME}:${CIRCLE_SHA1}"
            echo "uname:" $(uname -a)
            echo "arch: " $(arch)
      - run:
          name: Build image from Dockerfile
          command: |
            docker build \
              -f Dockerfile \
              --tag "${CIRCLE_PROJECT_REPONAME}:${CIRCLE_SHA1}" .
      - run:
          name: Save Docker image
          command: |
            set -ex
            mkdir -p workspace
            docker save ${CIRCLE_PROJECT_REPONAME}:${CIRCLE_SHA1} --output workspace/${CIRCLE_SHA1}.tar
      - persist_to_workspace:
          root: workspace
          paths:
            - '*.tar'

  run_script_inside_container:
    executor: my-executor
    steps:

      - setup_remote_docker:
          docker_layer_caching: true

      - checkout

      - attach_workspace:
          at: workspace

      - run: &import_image
          name: Import Docker image
          command: |
            set -ex
            docker load --input workspace/${CIRCLE_SHA1}.tar
      - run:
          name: Run script inside of container
          command: |
            docker run --rm \
              -e < REMOVED INTENTIONALLY > \
              ${CIRCLE_PROJECT_REPONAME}:${CIRCLE_SHA1}
  scan_container:
    executor: my-executor
    steps:
      - checkout

      - setup_remote_docker:
          docker_layer_caching: true

      - run:
          name: Security scan
          command: my_scan_script

workflows:
  build_container_and_scan:
    jobs:
      - build_container
      - run_script_inside_container:
          requires:
          - build_container
      - scan_container:
          requires:
          - build_container
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue - did you find a solution?

Comment: Hey @Alfie, at first I got to a middle ground.  For jobs like Lint, Unit Test or Integration Tests, I started to use only the CircleCI cimg images.  For these, it was overkill to use the bigger image that I created.  The cimg images are small and cached already so quick to use.   In my build container step, I was pulling from DockerHub.  When I added a "log in" step to Docker Hub, everything got better ( as I wasn't rate limited ).  Not sure this gives a perfect answer but hope the tips help ?